# Read the csv file store data in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have csv file like this
[image][1][1]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaBMF.png  which has 2 columns, I have read this csv file and stored data in dictionary, below is my code

```
import csv
with open('p1.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
pprint(mydict)
```

This above lines of code gives me output as follows:

```
{'00:00-00:15': '266.78',
 '00:15-00:30': '266.78',
 '00:30-00:45': '266.78',
 '00:45-01:00': '266.78',
 '01:00-01:15': '266.78',}
```

But i want this output in below form:

```
     {{'00:00-00:15': '266.78'},
     {'00:15-00:30': '266.78'},
     {'00:30-00:45': '266.78'},
     {'00:45-01:00': '266.78'},
     {'01:00-01:15': '266.78'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Put extra brackets around `rows[0]:rows[1]` to create multiple dictionaries. Keep in mind, the output you want (and this gives) is a `set` of dictionaries (`{1, 2, 3}` is set literal notation). You might want to use a list, by replacing the outer `{}` with `[]`

```
import csv
with open('p1.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mydict = [{rows[0]:rows[1]} for rows in reader]
pprint(mydict)
```

Comment: When I tried the code, I got at this line `mydict = {{rows[0]:rows[1]} for rows in reader}` the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: as @Evan said replace outer  `{}`  with `[]`
So it will be `mydict = [{rows[0]:rows[1]} for rows in reader]`

Comment: I also get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. This is because you cannot have a "`set` of dictionaries" — they're unhashable.

Comment: Prathamesh: Yes, but @Evan's answer also claims it's possible to create something impossible — something _they_ should correct — not you. I think it's obvious they didn't try running the code in they answer before posting it and this situation is why that's often a bad idea.

Comment: Evan: While fixing your code to get rid of the `TypeError` was an improvement, what's still in the rest of it is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

What you want appears to be a `set` of dictionaries, however that's impossible because dictionaries aren't hashable. You can workaround that restriction by defining your own `dict` subclass which is.

```
import csv
import hashlib
from pprint import pprint


class HashableDict(dict):
    """ Hashable dict subclass. """
    def __hash__(self):
        m = hashlib.sha256(b''.join(bytes(repr(key_value), encoding='utf8')
                                        for key_value in self.items()))
        return int.from_bytes(m.digest(), byteorder='big')


with open('p1.csv', mode='r', newline='') as infile:
    mydict = {HashableDict({row[0]:row[1]}) for row in csv.reader(infile)}

pprint(mydict, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
{{'00:00-00:15': '266.78'},
 {'00:15-00:30': '266.78'},
 {'00:30-00:45': '266.78'},
 {'00:45-01:00': '266.78'},
 {'01:00-01:15': '266.78'}}
```